# Draw a pointer on the edge of the screen that points to the target object behind tha back (invisible on the screen by the camera)

Tags: aframe

- Live example: https://aframe-aim-component.glitch.me/
- Try in Glitch: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/aframe-aim-component

We will see a blue line when we execute the sample code. It runs from a point 1 meter in front of the camera, to the position point of the red cube, which is behind and slightly away from the camera at the start. If we rotate the camera with the mouse to the left, we will turn to the red cube and the blue line will be drawn to the cube.

This blue bar is just an experiment to implement such an idea:

1. Draw an invisible line from a point in front of the camera, to the target object.
2. Find the coordinate on the device screen where the line intersects with the screen boundary.
3. Find the angle of intersection with the screen of this line.
4. Use HTML to display an arrow element on top of the canvas and rotate it in the direction of the invisible line.

Thanks to Piotr Adam Milewski for help in rendering the line ([AFRAME: Coordinates of the fixed point in front of the camera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74235676/aframe-coordinates-of-the-fixed-point-in-front-of-the-camera))

As a result, the following behavior is expected: If the target object, with the "aim" component, is behind the player (the invisible line crosses the screen boundary), then an arrow is displayed on the screen boundary, indicating to the player in which direction he needs to turn to see the object.

I'm new to 3D and don't understand a lot of things yet. Please help me to implement a directional arrow pointing to the object.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.3.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        AFRAME.registerComponent("aim", {
            init: function() {
                this._matAimRay = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color: 0x0000ff } );
                this._frustum = new THREE.Frustum();
            },
            play: function() {
                this._camera = this.el.sceneEl.camera;
            },
            pause: function() {
                this._camera = null;
            },
            remove: function () {
                this.el.sceneEl.removeChild(this._pointerEntity);
            },
            tick: function() {
                if (!!this._camera) {
                    if (!this._checkIsAtScreen(this._camera, this.el.object3D.position)) {
                        if (!this._pointerEntity) {
                            //create entity for pointer line
                            let pointerEntity = document.createElement("a-entity");
                            this._pointerEntity = pointerEntity;
                            this.el.sceneEl.appendChild(pointerEntity);
                        }

                        let posViewer = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, -100);
                        this._camera.localToWorld(posViewer);

                        const points = [];
                        points.push( posViewer, this.el.object3D.position );

                        const geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints( points );
                        const line = new THREE.Line( geometry, this._matAimRay );
                        this._pointerEntity.setObject3D("mesh", line );
                    } else if (!!this._pointerEntity) {
                        this.el.sceneEl.removeChild(this._pointerEntity);
                        this._pointerEntity = null;
                    }
                }
            },
            _checkIsAtScreen(camera, pointVector3) {
                camera.updateMatrix();
                camera.updateMatrixWorld();
                this._frustum.setFromProjectionMatrix(new THREE.Matrix4().multiplyMatrices(camera.projectionMatrix, camera.matrixWorldInverse));
                return this._frustum.containsPoint(pointVector3);
            }
        });
    </script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a-scene>
        <a-entity camera look-controls position="0 0 0"></a-entity>
        <a-box aim position="-5 0 5" color="red"></a-box>
    </a-scene>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

**UPDATE:**

I updated the example code:

1. The beam to the target object is visible only when the object is not visible to the camera. The same way the pointer (2d compass) will be hidden from the user screen
2. Moved the point in front of the camera from 1 meter to 100 meters then, so that there is no effect when the beam is interrupted in the edge of the screen when the object is directly behind the camera. With more distance, the chance of this decreasing.

**UPDATE 2 (working (bad) example)!!!**

There is progress in my research. I don't fully understand how :) But it's starting to work. The problem is in the hautticity of determining the intersection of the imaginary line with furstum and in filtering the valid point, which makes the arrows move jerkily. If you set isValidScreenCoordinates == true, the arrows begin to move smoothly, but there are strange disappearances in the corners in Y...

Now there is something to build on, I will be very happy if you point out my mistakes in the study and contribute to it, to make the movement of arrows smoothly and accurately :))

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>
        .aim-arrow {
            position: absolute; 
            z-index: 100000; 
            font-size: 50px;
            opacity: 0;
            visibility: hidden;
            transition: opacity 0ms ease;
        }
        .aim-arrow.visible {
            opacity: 1;
            visibility: visible;
            transition: opacity 1050ms ease;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.3.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        AFRAME.registerComponent("aim", {
            schema: {
                color: {type:'color', default: 'orange'}
            },
            init: function() {
                this._frustum = new THREE.Frustum();

                let pointerEl = document.createElement("div");
                pointerEl.textContent = `◄`;
                pointerEl.setAttribute("class", "aim-arrow");
                this._pointerEl = pointerEl;
                document.querySelector("body").appendChild(this._pointerEl);
            },
            update: function(oldData) {
                this._pointerEl.style.color = this.data.color;
            },
            play: function() {
                this._camera = this.el.sceneEl.camera;
            },
            pause: function() {
                this._camera = null;
            },
            remove: function () {
                this._pointerEl.parentElement.removeChild(this._pointerEl);
            },
            tick: function() {
                if (!!this._camera) {
                    if (!this._checkIsAtScreen(this._camera, this.el.object3D.position)) {

                        this._containerWidth = window.innerWidth;
                        this._containerHeight = window.innerHeight;

                        let posViewer = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, (this._camera.near + this._camera.far / 2) * -1);
                        this._camera.localToWorld(posViewer);

                        //find intersections
                        let line3 = new THREE.Line3();
                        line3.set(posViewer, this.el.object3D.position);
                        let intersectionPoint = new THREE.Vector3();

                        let isValidScreenCoordinates = false;
                        for (let i = 0; i < this._frustum.planes.length; i++) {
                            this._frustum.planes[i].intersectLine(line3, intersectionPoint);
                            if(!!intersectionPoint) {
                                let screenCoordinate = this._vector3ToScreenXY(this._camera, intersectionPoint, this._containerWidth, this._containerHeight);
                                if (!!screenCoordinate) {
                                    isValidScreenCoordinates = (screenCoordinate.x >= 0) && (screenCoordinate.y >= 0) && (screenCoordinate.x <= this._containerWidth) && (screenCoordinate.y <= this._containerHeight);
                                    if (isValidScreenCoordinates) {
                                        this._placePointer(screenCoordinate, this._containerWidth, this._containerHeight);
                                        //display pointer
                                        this._pointerEl.classList.toggle("visible", true);
                                    } else {
                                        console.log('not valid', screenCoordinate);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } else  {
                        //hide pointer
                        this._pointerEl.classList.toggle("visible", false);
                    }
                }
            },
            _checkIsAtScreen(camera, pointVector3) {
                this._frustum.setFromProjectionMatrix(new THREE.Matrix4().multiplyMatrices(camera.projectionMatrix, camera.matrixWorldInverse));
                return this._frustum.containsPoint(pointVector3);
            },
            _vector3ToScreenXY(camera, vector3, containerWidth, containerHeight) {
                let result = null;
                let pos = vector3.clone();
                let projScreenMat = new THREE.Matrix4();
                projScreenMat.multiply( camera.projectionMatrix, camera.matrixWorldInverse );
                projScreenMat.multiplyVector3( pos );

                let x = ( pos.x + 1 ) * containerWidth / 2;
                let y = ( - pos.y + 1) * containerHeight / 2;

                if (!isNaN(x) && !isNaN(y)) {
                    result = { x, y };
                }

                return result;
            },
            _findAimPointerAngle(pointerXYCoordinate, containerWidth, containerHeight) {
                let cx = pointerXYCoordinate.x;
                let cy = pointerXYCoordinate.y;
                let ex = containerWidth / 2;
                let ey = containerHeight / 2;

                let dy = ey - cy;
                let dx = ex - cx;
                let theta = Math.atan2(dy, dx); // range (-PI, PI]
                theta *= 180 / Math.PI; // rads to degs, range (-180, 180]
                if (theta < 0) theta = 360 + theta; // range [0, 360)
                return theta;
            },
            _placePointer(screenCoordinate, containerWidth, containerHeight) {
                let angle = this._findAimPointerAngle(screenCoordinate, containerWidth, containerHeight);
                this._pointerEl.style.left = `${screenCoordinate.x}px`;
                this._pointerEl.style.top = `${screenCoordinate.y}px`;
                this._pointerEl.style.transformOrigin = "0% 0%";
                this._pointerEl.style.transform = `rotate(${angle}deg) translate(0%, -50%)`;
            }
        });
    </script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a-scene>
        <a-entity camera look-controls="wasd-controls: false; pointerLockEnabled: true" wasd-controls position="0 0 0"></a-entity>
        <a-box aim="color: red" position="-5 0 5" color="red"></a-box>
        <a-box aim="color: blue" position="5 0 5" color="blue"></a-box>
    </a-scene>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Something like a compass on the XZ plane?

Comment: Yes, like 2d compass on user screen, i think XY plane. Please see the picture I just attached to the main post. This compass should help the user understand which way he needs to turn to see the target object, which is not currently on the screen.

Comment: I just created public repo for this component and prepared example page(index.html). Plase, take a code from git, i think, it should be more convenient. https://github.com/arkonsolutions/aframe-aim-component